# how does the SUB instruction work in assembly AVR

Tags: assembly, avr, instruction-set

how does the SUB instruction work in AVR assembly? does it take the twos compliment and add it or does it function differently? If I subtract two 8- bit numbers, say 1 - 2 and the answer is -1, should I expect the twos complement of 1 or some other value?

Edit: I'm not sure how to think about the question when thinking about numbers higher than 128, my understanding of twos compliment is that you half the magnitude of numbers you can count to, but if I give the SUB instruction to do:

2 - 255

what do the bit operations look like? My understanding is that the twos compliment of 255 requires nine bits (100000001), does it just overflow in an 8 bit system? Would the math look like:

00000010 + 00000001 = 00000011

Comment: I'd be interested to know a *production* chip that doesn't use 2's complement. Yes AVR does use 2's complement.

Comment: twos complement of 255 (8-bit word) is exactly 1, and it doesn't overflow

Comment: @xiver77: `-255` is a different number from `1`, unless you truncate to 8 bits.  (But `255` itself can't be represented as an 8-bit *signed* number, so I guess you mean that the bit-pattern `0xff` represents `-1`, and negating it to `+1` doesn't overflow.)

Comment: AVR uses 2's complement signed integers, so SUB's effect on the bit-pattern is always the same as what unsigned binary subtraction would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly language does not do subtract nor does the machine code, the logic in the processor does.  And yes, it does use addition to do subtraction.

2 - 255

from grade school

2 - 255 = 2 + (-255)

and we know from first semester programming class, invert and add one

2 - 255 = 2 + (-255) = 2 + ~255 + 1

And now it is easy to do with an adder

```
         1
  00000010
+ 00000000
===========

 000000001
  00000010
+ 00000000
===========
  00000011
```

Now that looks strange, but if you are thinking 8 bit with a number like 255 that is -1 signed.   so 2 - (-1) = 2 + 1 = 3.  And that makes sense.  The beauty of twos complement is that we can use the same logic and not care about unsigned or signed, you get the same answer for the same bit patterns.

As pointed out in comments 255 for an 8 bit number can only be unsigned.  but the same bits are a -1.

You example is a tough one to visualize.  Since it all works the same 4 bits is easier to describe here than 8.  So 0 to 15 or -8 to 7 for unsigned or signed.

So if we did 12 + 5 we would get 17 but that is an unsigned overflow, let's try:

```
     0
  1100
 +0101
======


 11000
  1100
 +0101
======
  0101
```

Carry out is set so we had an unsigned overflow.

What about -7 - 4 = -11

```
 10011
  1001
+ 1100
=======
  0110
```

which is 6, but: look at the carry in and carry out of the msbit.  They are not the same, so this is a signed overflow.  Another way to say it is look at the msbits of the operands and the result, if the operand msbits are the same but the result is not, then it is a signed overflow.

If we had another bit 10110 is 1001+1 = 1011 so -11.

It works for 8 or 32 or 64 or 128 bits.   Multiplication and division can have signed vs unsigned, but addition and subtraction due to the nature of twos complement, the bit patterns use an adder and nothing special for signed or unsigned.   It is the programmer, not the logic, that cares.

Now when it comes to cascading, that does matter, in particular with subtraction.   Not shown above, you can try it yourself, but when doing unsigned a carry out of the msbit is an unsigned overflow of course, but also if the processor uses flags, that becomes the carry flag.   But for subtraction a 1 (and not signed overflow) means not borrow.  The math did not need to do a borrow (if you did it longhand and not the invert and add one thing). Which is good but some processors invert that and make the carry flag a borrow flag for subtract. Others do not invert and make it a not borrow flag for subtraction.   If there is a subtract with borrow then it matters if they inverted or not as to how the lsbit carry in is handled.  Now this is buried in the logic and "just works" but since you asked how these things work.

Also better processor documentation (Read: ARM) shows you a table of conditionals and what flags are what.   Which will not be the same from processor to processor if the carry out is a borrow vs not borrow for subtract, since subtract is use for compare instructions...

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction operation works as long as you subtract two equal types of data. It's mean you can subtract `signed` - `signed` or `unsigned` - `unsigned`. You can't mix signed and unsigned type.

First case:

```
; xl, yl is considered as signed 
ldi xl, 2     ;first op  = 2
ldi yl, 255   ;second op = -1
sub xl, yl    ;result    = 3  because (2-(-1))
brvs overflow ;test if overflow occurred (no it's false now)
```

Second case:

```
; xl, yl is considered as unsigned 
ldi xl, 2     ;first op  = 2
ldi yl, 255   ;second op = 255
sub xl, yl    ;result    = invalid   because 2-255 is negative 
brlo overflow ;test if first operand is lower as second (yes it's true now)
```

If you really want subtract 2 - 255 you must use two byte for both numbers. Because result is -253 and valid range for one byte is only -128 to 127

```
; xh:xl, yh:yl is considered as signed 
ldi xh, 0
ldi xl, 2     ;first op  = 2
ldi yh, 0
ldi yl, 255   ;second op = 255
sub xl, yl
sbc xh, yh    ;result is -235 (0xFF03)
brvs overflow ;test if overflow occurred (no it's false now)
```

Comment: You can subtract signed from unsigned by sign-extending one input, zero-extending the other (to the destination width) so the operation can't overflow (as you say in the last section).  Also, unsigned +- signed is basically meaningful if you don't mind wrapping, or your inputs *don't* wrap.  e.g. `255 + 3` or `255 - (-3)` wraps to unsigned `2` (or signed `2`) in 8-bit.  The CPU won't set flags in a way that tells you anything useful about signed or unsigned overflow, though, only about the final result having its MSB set or not.

Comment: Doesn't AVR `sbc` have an immediate form, like `sbci xh, 0`?  You don't actually need to materialize the high half in a register for zero-extension.

Comment: I can't agree in all with you. If do sign and zero extension you convert both data type to signed type. Second statement regarding flags is OK. I must use suitable flag test regarding checking overflow case.
Yes, AVR have `sbci` instruction, but it's only kind of optimization, which here hiding principle

Comment: Yes, `sbci` with zero is just an optimization, totally separate from the conceptual issue.  Re: overflow, not all operations need to be overflow-checked.  Also, after extending 8-bit inputs to 16-bit, signed overflow is impossible.  (Carry / borrow is possible, and happens for addition if either input was negative so its high half is FF, same for most such subtractions.  But if you consider both values as signed after sign and zero extension, unsigned overflow is the wrong thing to look for.)

Comment: Sorry for wrong sentence regarding overflow checking. It should have meant 'must' in case of I want know if result is ok or not. `BRVS` check overflow for signed. `BRLO` or `BRCS` (it's same op code) check overflow(better underflow) for unsigned in case using SUB instruction before. Which unsigned overflow test you mean as wrong?

Comment: Your `brvs overflow` can never be taken, because the inputs are 8-bit but you're producing a 16-bit signed result. It can always hold the 9bit result without overflow. Similarly, checking for unsigned overflow with the carry flag would also not really be meaningful after sign-extending one input.  e.g. `250u - (-3)` would correctly give `253`, but would get there by wrapping through zero if you look at it as unsigned.  You only want to know about cases like `1u - 3` wraps to `65534` (`fffe`).  I wasn't saying anything was wrong with code in your answer, just the hypothetical thing I mentioned.